# How to use layered thrift transports in a java server

Tags: java, thrift

I want to use the following thrift transports on top of each other.

- layered transport: zlib transport
- layered transport: framed transport
- endpoint transport: socket

I can only set 1 transport factory in a server, but actually, I have to set the zlib factory and the framed factory. For instance:

```
new TServer.Args(new TServerSocket(port)).transportFactory(new TFramedTransport.Factory());
```

How can I set both transports on the server side in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom factory that creates the nested transports:

```
  public class MyNestedFactory extends TTransportFactory {
    @Override
    public TTransport getTransport(TTransport base) {
      return new TZlibTransport(new TFramedTransport(base));
    }
  }
```

You can then pass this factory to your server args:

```
new TServer.Args(new TServerSocket(port))
              .transportFactory(new MyNestedFactory())
```